# Can you insert a marker symbol at a specific scale?

Tags: arcmap, symbology, scale, markers

I have a map that is consistently used at a 1:500 scale. I want to be able to add structures to the map to view and move them around to get the best fit. The end user is new to GIS and I am trying to limit the amount of editing they need to do and would like to use marker symbols. They can easily be added to the map, rotated and moved. I need the structures to come in at the proper scale. Currently this is being done using a paper copy of the map and scaled paper cut outs of the structures. Is it possible to do this using ArcMap 10 of 10.1?

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at data driven pages. http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/What_are_Data_Driven_Pages/00s90000003m000000/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but not what I am looking for. I really just want to insert a marker symbol and be confident that it displayed to scale

Comment: we need to do exactly this too - did you find a solution?

Comment: @LynnBiggs I never found a solution. I ended up making a polygon the approximate shape and size I wanted the marker and then resizing the marker symbol to fit.